# What is the name of the symbol used to depict 'eat and drink'?

Tags: vocabulary

[image: Eat and drink symbol]

This is the symbol I am talking about, usually used in Google Maps

Answer (score 1):

Those are generally called **icons**, or just **symbols**— as in "international symbol" or sometimes [ISO symbols](http://www.iso.org/iso/graphical-symbols_booklet.pdf)

(Note that, in fact, Google do not, I think, use ISO symbols; they have a building or two full of skilled illustrators to draw their own, superior, "symbols" or "icons".)

In most cases there's no particular name for any one symbol.  For example, there are different symbols representing different types of *hazards*. See [Wikipedia's Hazard symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_symbol)

For what it's worth, the Unicode value is: 1F374 or 1F37D
and is referred to as simply **[Fork and Knife](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf)**.

[image: screenshot of U1F300.pdf from the Unicode website showing the glyph labeled 1F374]

Regarding the difference between *icon* and *symbol*.  The term *icon* is very much used with apps on *Samsung* and *Apple* telephones, and is very often used in describing "button-like-things" on flat-screen software generally.  So I'd be inclined to use the word *symbol*.